# Rising Edge Demux

Tags: sound, latch, addressing

I'm trying to create a demux for the YM2610 sound chip.

The sound chip selects whether to set the low bits or high bits of the address with a single pulse; the rising edge should trigger a latch for the low bits and the falling edge should trigger a latch for the high bits.

I can only find demux chips that latch on the falling edge of their latch enable pins. This will work for the high bits but not for the low bits.

How can I turn the rising edge of the pulse into a falling edge so that I can properly trigger the low address latch?

Edit: maybe I could use an inverter to create an inverse of the pulse to create a negative edge at the correct time?

[image]

Comment: yes, you could use an inverter